# How can I make my web app interact with a SQL database?

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm attempting to create a web application which will allow me to input data via form, and then save it in a SQL database.

My form looks like this.
[image: screenshot 1]

I've been following YouTube tutorials to help code the backend, but when I click the Save Data button, I get the following error in my console log.

[image: screenshot 2]

Here's the code in my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');
 
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
 
const db = mysql.createConnection({
user: 'root',
host: 'localhost',
port: '3307',
password: '',
database: 'aemonthlysitrep',
});
 
app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
const aeattendances_type1 = req.body.aeattendances_type1;
const aeattendances_type2 = req.body.aeattendances_type2;
const aeattendances_other = req.body.aeattendances_other;
const fourhours_patients_type1 = req.body.fourhours_patients_type1;
const fourhours_patients_type2 = req.body.fourhours_patients_type2;
const fourhours_patients_other = req.body.fourhours_patients_other;
const fourtotwelvehours_patients = req.body.fourtotwelvehours_patients;
const twelvehours_patients = req.body.twelvehours_patients;
const aeemergencyadmissions_type1 = req.body.aeemergencyadmissions_type1;
const aeemergencyadmissions_type2 = req.body.aeemergencyadmissions_type2;
const aeemergencyadmissions_other = req.body.aeemergencyadmissions_other;
const emergencyadmissions_other = req.body.emergencyadmissions_other;
 
db.query(
    "INSERT INTO data (aeattendances_type1, aeattendances_type2, aeattendances_other, >4hours_patients_type1, >4hours_patients_type2, >4hours_patients_other, 4-12hour_patients, >12hours_patients, aeemergencyadmissions_type1, aeemergencyadmissions_type2, aeemergencyadmissions_other, emergencyadmissions_other) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [aeattendances_type1, aeattendances_type2, aeattendances_other, fourhours_patients_type1, fourhours_patients_type2, fourhours_patients_other, fourtotwelvehours_patients, twelvehours_patients, aeemergencyadmissions_type1, aeemergencyadmissions_type2, aeemergencyadmissions_other, emergencyadmissions_other ],
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.send("Data added successfully.");
     }
    }
    );
});  
 
app.listen(3000, ()=> {
console.log("The server is running.")
});
```

And below is the code in my App.js file:

```
 import './App.css';
    import { useState } from "react"; 
    import Axios from 'axios';

    function App() {

    const [aeattendances_type1, setAeattendances_type1] = useState(0);
    const [aeattendances_type2, setAeattendances_type2] = useState(0);
    const [aeattendances_other, setAeattendances_other] = useState(0);
    const [fourhours_patients_type1, setFourhours_patients_type1] = useState(0);
    const [fourhours_patients_type2, setFourhours_patients_type2] = useState(0);
    const [fourhours_patients_other, setFourhours_patients_other] = useState(0);
    const [fourtotwelvehours_patients, setFourtotwelvehours_patients] = useState(0);
    const [twelvehours_patients, setTwelvehours_patients] = useState(0);
    const [aeemergencyadmissions_type1, setAeemergencyadmissions_type1] = useState(0);
    const [aeemergencyadmissions_type2, setAeemergencyadmissions_type2] = useState(0);
    const [aeemergencyadmissions_other, setAeemergencyadmissions_other] = useState(0);
    const [emergencyadmissions_other, setEmergencyadmissions_other] = useState(0);


    const saveData = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create", { 
      aeattendances_type1: aeattendances_type1,
      aeattendances_type2: aeattendances_type2,
      aeattendances_other: aeattendances_other,
      fourhours_patients_type1: fourhours_patients_type1,
      fourhours_patients_type2: fourhours_patients_type2,
      fourhours_patients_other: fourhours_patients_other,
      fourtotwelvehours_patients: fourtotwelvehours_patients,
      twelvehours_patients: twelvehours_patients,
      aeemergencyadmissions_type1: aeemergencyadmissions_type1,
      aeemergencyadmissions_type2: aeemergencyadmissions_type2,
      aeemergencyadmissions_other: aeemergencyadmissions_other,
      emergencyadmissions_other: emergencyadmissions_other,
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Success.");
    });
    };

    return (
    <div className="App">
      <link
           rel="stylesheet"
           href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
           crossOrigin="anonymous"
      />
       <div>
        <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colSpan={10} scope="col"><p className="text-end px-5 pt-2">Attendances by A&amp;E Type</p></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" />
                <th scope="col"><center>Type 1</center></th>
                <th scope="col"><center>Type 2</center></th>
                <th scope="col"><center>Other</center></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of A&amp;E Attendances</th>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeattendances_type1(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeattendances_type2(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeattendances_other(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              </tr><tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of Patients who have had a total time in A&amp;E of  <br />over 4 hours from arrival to discharge,transfer of admission</th>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setFourhours_patients_type1(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setFourhours_patients_type2(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div className="col p-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setFourhours_patients_other(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have waited 4-12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-7 p-4 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setFourtotwelvehours_patients(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have over 12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-7 p-4 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setTwelvehours_patients(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colSpan={10} scope="col"><p className="text-end px-5 pt-2">Number of Admissions</p></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have waited 4-12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeemergencyadmissions_type1(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have over 12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeemergencyadmissions_type2(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have waited 4-12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setAeemergencyadmissions_other(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Number of patient who have over 12 hours in A&amp;E from <br />decision to admit to admission</th>
                <td colSpan={3}>
                  <div className="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <input type="number" onChange={(event) => {
                        setEmergencyadmissions_other(event.target.value);
                        }}  className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="sitrep col-6 mx-auto">
            <button onClick={saveData}>Save Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     );
     }
    
    export default App;
```

I'm unsure of what to try next to resolve the error, the connection details are all correct so I'm a bit stumped as to why it's refusing to connect or save the data in my SQL database.

I would greatly appreciate any advice/pointers on what I can do next?

Thank you.

Kind regard,

Adam

Comment: Have you tested the API individually? You should use something like Postman to test your API and make sure it is working properly before adding it to your application. That way you can narrow down if your bug is with the backend or the frontend.

Comment: Post your error as text rather than image.

Comment: The server is listening on port 3000 and your AJAX call goes to port 3001, therefore the browser never contacts the server and your code doesn't even runs.